# Logo behind the navigation bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to edit a website and put the logo in the same line as the navigation bar. The problem is, my logo hides behind the bar. I've tried using float, but with no results. The position of both is good, I just don't know how to make the logo display on top of the navigation bar.

[image: screenshot]

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 80px;

.navigation-bar > a {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can we get the HTML for this? I think it may be an XY problem.

Comment: Probably you misplaced `html`. Is `.logo` element inside `.navigation-bar` element?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: A screenshot is not sufficient. I understand what you are trying to achieve, what I don't understand is how your HTML is formed.

Comment: use z-index:99999; in your .logo class

Answer (score 0):

Try This code for CSS & HTML

```html
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" alt="Cryptic Concepts" hight="10px" width="200px"/></a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="News.html">News</a>
    <a class="active">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is an example with the Google logo, I got the code from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_header.asp)
it looks like this [image: Nav Bar]